# Error handling in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to develop error handling at single point in my expressJS app.

I have added following code in expressJS configuration :

```
app.use(app.router);
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.error('ExpressJS : error!!!');
});
```

So, any error occurred in app then above function should get execute so that I can handle error in custom way.

But, above function is not getting execute on javascript error or on following code :

```
throw new Error('something broke!');
```

I have read :
http://expressjs.com/guide/error-handling.html and 
http://derickbailey.com/2014/09/06/proper-error-handling-in-expressjs-route-handlers/
But, still I am not able to make generic error handling in my expressJS app.
Can anyone explain how I will handle any app error at single point?

Comment: If only it were that simple. An error can occur almost anywhere, you would have to catch it where it occurs, You can of course use a single route to respond to server errors, but you can't catch all and any errors in that route.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not by express, but nodejs, you can try

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Because "throw" is javascript, not under expressjs control.

For those errors, like routing in express, you should able to catch with app.error or app.use(function(err .. as other advised, which would available req, res object too.

```
app.error(function(err, req, res, next){
    //check error information and respond accordingly
});

//newer versions
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {

});
```

Comment: Is it possible to get request and response object in above code?

Comment: as far as i know. nope, throw is javacript code, and this is javascript code. both run in nodejs, not by express. or try app.error

Comment: Is there any workaround for request and response object in above case?

Comment: @SachinKumbharkar, i am not sure, but there is app object attach somewhere as far as i know, you can try app.req or app.res

Answer (score 0):

actually , you need put the error-handling in the end of the router ,

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});
```

if you have the error logger , you must put it in front of the error-handling .

```
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(logErrors);            // log the error
app.use(clientErrorHandler);   // catch the client error , maybe part of the router
app.use(errorHandler);         // catch the error occured in the whole router
```

and you may define several error-handling middleware , each error-handling catch different level error .

Comment: throw new Error('something broke!');

Comment: i mean you need use the middleware to delivery error :
if(err) next(err) , and then  the error-handling middleware will receive the error .

Answer (score 0):

In express, you trigger the route error handling by calling `next()` with a parameter, as follows:

```
app.get('/api/resource',function(req, res, next) {
   //some code, then err occurs
   next(err);
})
```

calling `next()` will trigger the next middleware/handler in your chain. If you pass a parameter to it (as in `next(err)` ), then it will skip the next handlers and trigger the error handling middleware.

As far as I know, if you simply `throw` an error, it won't be caught by express and you may crash your node instance.

Remember you can have as many error handlers as you need:

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    //do some processing...
    //let's say you want more error middleware to trigger, then keep on calling next with a parameter
    next(err);
});
```